# Cannot use Hook Inside React Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I faced an `invalid hook call error` when using the `useEffect` hook. The docs only specified that this problem occurred because of either a version mismatch or my function call is incorrect.

Can anyone please check which part did I made my mistake?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { Typography, Card, Avatar, Row, Col, Tooltip } from "antd";
import {
  UserOutlined,
  BookOutlined,
  LogoutOutlined,
  SettingOutlined
} from "@ant-design/icons";

const { Text } = Typography;

export default function ProfileCard() {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/accounts/api/" + username)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setItems(result.items);
        },
        (error) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
        }
      )
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <Card
        size="small"
        style={{ width: 300 }}
        actions={[...]}
      >
        <Row justify="center" style={{ marginBottom: -3 }}>
          <Col>
            <Text strong style={{ fontSize: 17 }}>
              { items.username }
            </Text>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Card>
    </>
  );
}
```

Please assume that all dependencies are installed and `username` is a predefined string.

Sincerely,

cpy24

Comment: You need to wrap your fetch into useCallback. And what's your `username` variable? Looks like it was not defined.

Comment: > Please assume that all dependencies are installed and username is a predefined string.

I already specified that in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC you have to declare the function inside the useEffect

```
  useEffect(() => {
     const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
           let response = await fetch(`/accounts/api/${username}`);
           let result = await response.json();

           setIsLoaded(true);
           setItems(result.items);
        } catch(err) {
           console.error(err);
           setIsLoaded(true);
           setItems(err);
        }
     };

     fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/accounts/api/" + username)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setItems(result.items);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
      });
  }, []);
```

use `catch` for Error.

Comment: @cpy24 btw, where did you get `username` in `<ProfileCard />`?

Comment: It's declared in my html document where I called the file:


{% block js %}
<script>
  let username = "{{ user.username }}";
</script>
<script src="{% static 'core/index.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock js %}

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the fetch with a useCallback hook as suggested in the comments

```
const fetchData = useCallback(() => {
   fetch("/accounts/api/" + username)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setItems(result.items);
        },
        (error) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
        }
      )
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
  fetchData()
}, [fetchData])
```

Comment: hmm i'm not sure then cause it doesn't seem like you're breaking the rules of hooks. You can try to follow the debugging steps in this link: https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html

Answer (score 1):

what are the versions of react and react-dom? (I cannot comment)

Comment: package.json:
```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.1",
    "antd-dayjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.6.0",
    "html-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.10.3",
    "antd": "^4.3.5",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1"
  }
```

Comment: can you add this line to your webpack file and try? alias: {
        react: path.resolve('./node_modules/react')
      }

Comment: Webpack doesn't recognize alias though. Said invalid configuration object... unknown property 'alias'

Comment: can you show its <Route />? also try to delete yarn.lock, package-lock.json, node_modules, dist, kind of cache and build files and then run yarn or npm install to install libraries again.

Comment: You may try the following article [link](https://robkendal.co.uk/blog/2019-12-22-solving-react-hooks-invalid-hook-call-warning/), your code is fine and should work.

Answer (score 0):

I really appreciated those who tried to answer my question. It turned out that I loaded this component inside another and that's a violation of rules. Upvoted to all those that tried to help out along the way.